# Define a projective transformation in metapost

Tags: diagrams, draw, metapost, transformation

The Metapost contains the affine transformation of 2D-plane, in the homogeneous coordinates, i.e., under the identification of `$(x,y)$` in 2D-plane with `$(x,y,1)$`, the representation matrix is given by

```
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix}
T_{xx}&T_{xy}&T_x\\
T_{yx}&T_{yy}&T_y\\
0     &0     &1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
```

Now, my question is that how can we define a projective transformation by assign its components as the affine transformation?

```
transform T;
xxpart T=a11; xypart T=a12; xpart T=a13;
yxpart T=a21; yypart T=a22; ypart T=a23;
zxpart T=a31; zypart T=a32; zpart T=a33;
```

and use it as the affine transformation too:

```
z0=(1,2); 
z1=z0 transformed T;
show z1;
```

---

The background math of projective math can be found at [this site](https://fzheng.me/2016/01/14/proj-transformation/), from where we know that

- a 3x3 matrix  `$A$` represents a projective matrix iff. `$\det A\neq0$`;
- to get the coordinates of `z1` (as given in the example) by acting a projective transformation `T` on `z0`, we only need to do matrix multiplication as follows

```
A(part(z0),part(z0),1)^t
```

where `A=(a_{ij})` is the representing matrix of `T`, and then divide first two components of the above result by the last one, note that the above results is again a 1x3 column matrix (denoted by `X=(x1,x2,x3)` for simplicity), i.e.,

```
xpart(z1)=x1/x3; 
ypart(z1)=x2/x3;
```

So, I want to define a function/transformation which acts almost the same as affine transformation, but it's more general such that the last row in the affine matrix can be arbitrary.

Comment: A `transform` only has six parts in MP, so your `zxpart` etc do not exist in the current language.

Comment: Denis Roegel's [`mp3d`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/mp3d) package is probably the best implementation of projective transformations but it is getting very long in the tooth, and it is not easy to use.

Comment: And even speaking as an MP fan, I think that `Asymptote` provides much better support for 3D projections, so you might be better spending some time learning that.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is “no you can't”.  At least not in the way you describe.

To define a projective transformation as you describe you would need a data structure that could hold all nine components, but the built-in `transform` data type only has six components.  By implication MP fixes the "last row" of the theoretical 3x3 matrix as `0, 0, 1` and provides no mechanisms to change it or store the values.  So what you suggest is just not available as part of the core language.

But MP is very extensible, so you could write a set of macros to store and work with three-dimensional vectors, and 3x3 transformations, and projections onto a plane.

If you want to see a fairly complete set that already does this, then you might start with [mp3d](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/mp3d) and see if you can write something better.